# Toggle between relative and absolute line numbers: Lisp Syntax

Tags: line-numbers

I need to define a function that toggles between value of `display-line-numbers` but can't figure out what's the correct lisp syntax to do so.
Here's what I want to do:

- Check if value of `display-line-numbers` set to `t` (absolute line numbers), change it to `relative`
- Else (it will be set to relative) change it to absolute (`t`).

Here's what I tried which is full of errors. Not having a very good hand at lisp

```lisp
(defun cc/toggle-line-numbering ()
  "Toggle line numbering between absolute and relative."
  (interactive)
  (if (= (describe-variable display-line-numbers) "relative")
      (setq display-line-numbers t)
    (setq display-line-numbers 'relative)))
```

Comment: Aka `(setq display-line-numbers (if (eq ...) t 'relative))`.

Comment: Thanks @Drew. This is short, simple and does the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`describe-variable` retrieves the documentation of a variable, it doesn't do anything with the value of the variable. You just want to test to see if the value of the variable is `eq` to something.

```
(defun cc/toggle-line-numbering ()
  "Toggle line numbering between absolute and relative."
  (interactive)
  (if (eq display-line-numbers 'relative)
      (setq display-line-numbers t)
    (setq display-line-numbers 'relative)))
```